# How do I use the map returned by jooq's fetchMap?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm using jooq, and I'm liking the fetchMap(Field) method. It works great if I want to use a single field as the key. Now, I'd like to fetch a map using two fields as the key. The fetchMap(Field[]) method returns a map with Record as the key. I have the values of the fields in the key, but I'm not sure how to convert them to a Record object so that I can grab the value from the map.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to instantiate a Record from a set of field values.

More info: I've got a table of provincial reports, for each week of the year. The table key is (province_id, week_number).
I can do this...

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.ORACLE);
Map<Record, ReportRecord> results = create.selectFrom(Tables.Report).fetchMap(new Field[]{Tables.Report.province_id, Tables.Report.week_number});
```

But now, let's say I have a province_id of 2, and a week_number of 42. I want to create a Record from that, so I can do

```
ReportRecord report = results.get(record);
```

Right now, I've switched to calling

```
Result<ReportRecord> results = create.selectFrom(Tables.Report).fetch();
```

, iterating over it, and creating a map myself. It's working, but I'd really like to know how the fetchMap method is meant to be used. Couldn't find anything in the jooq manual or the javadoc.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Could you explain this a more in detail with a code example?

Comment: Ok, I added some more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, there actually isn't a very easy way to do this. What you can do is:

```
Record record = create.newRecord(Report.province_id, Report.week_number);
record.setValue(Report.province_id, 2);
record.setValue(Report.week_number, 42);
ReportRecord report = results.get(record);
```

Agreed, that's a bit verbose and not very user friendly. This should be improved in [jOOQ 3.3 with #2847](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2847)

Comment: Certainly a bit verbose, but at least that's doable. Thanks very much. Appreciated.